# Exception handling with recursive async/await

Tags: c#

Consider the following code:

```
void TopLevelCaller() {
    RecursiveAwaiter();
}

async Task RecursiveAwaiter() {
    var result = await ReceiveDataAsync();
    FireEvent(result);
    RecursiveAwaiter();
}
```

Suppose `ReceiveDataAsync` fails with an exception.
Is it possible modify the code to catch this exception in the `TopLevelCaller()` such that all error handling can be done in the class where `TopLevelCaller()` exists?

It would be better to let the implementer handle the error like so:

```
void TopLevelCaller() {
    try {
        RecursiveAwaiter();
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Something went wrong. Handle appropriately.
    }
}
```

than to have something like:

```
async Task RecursiveAwaiter() {
    try {
        var result = await ReceiveDataAsync();
        FireEvent(result);
        RecursiveAwaiter();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        FireExceptionEvent(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: async/await throws `AggregateException`, if I'm not mistaken.  Wouldn't that suffice for what you are looking for?

Comment: *Don't* use `async avoid`, it's only meant for event handlers. Why don't you use `await RecursiveAwaiter()`? This will throw the exception.

Comment: @Tim not exactly. It's `await` that will either throw the actual exception, or `AggregateException` if more than one are thrown.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, but shouldn't it be `await RecursiveAwaiter()` to be able to catch it there?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `async void` is not only for event handlers. It may be good to warn about it in a comment, but there are valid use cases for `async void` other than event handlers, and the name `TopLevelCaller()` suggests strongly to me that the OP understands this and is *correctly* using `async void`.

Comment: @hvd Not really - `async` without `await` is useless and even generates warnings. The signature could easily be `void TopLevelCaller()` and nothing would change. This would suggest the OP isn't aware of what `async/await` actually does or the dangers of `async void`

Comment: You should await `RecursiveAwaiter` in `TopLevelCaller` method and also `RecursiveAwaiter`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You posted two sentences in your comment, I responded to the first of those, and even after your last comment I'm having trouble seeing the relation between the two. Yes, it should probably be `await RecursiveAwaiter()`, but I don't see how that means the use of `async void` is wrong. Yes, currently, the method could be `void RecursiveAwaiter()` without `async`, but as soon as `RecursiveAwaiter()` is changed to `await RecursiveAwaiter()`, then the `async` needs to be restored anyway.

Comment: Just to clarify, `async/void` without `await` was a typo. I originally wrote `await   RecursiveAwaiter()` in the `TopLevelCaller()`, but cut it for conciseness but forget to remove the `async` modifier. That being said, either `void` w/o `await` or `async/await` shouldn't really matter for the question asked.

Comment: @lejon `void T() { R(); }` and `async void T() { await R(); }` have significant differences in how they handle exceptions from `R`, and your question is specifically about handling the exceptions.

Comment: @lejon Actually, `await` is what matters. `async` is only syntactic sugar. `await` is what reads the results of a task and throws any exceptions that occurred, allowing you to catch them. Otherwise, you have an orphaned Task that will never be checked for failures

Comment: @hvd Agreed. But I intentionally left out as much code as possible in the `TopLevelCaller()` in an attempt to allow for clear modification of the code to achieve what I ask.

Answer (score 1):

```
async void TopLevelCaller()
```

async void is almost always bad idea. It is designed for WPF control events. This is fire and forget function so i.e. you won't be able to catch exceptions which TopLevelCaller throws. It should be working:

```
async Task TopLevelCaller() {
    try {
        await RecursiveAwaiter();
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Something went wrong. Handle appropriately.
    }
}
```